# Integrate Mender.io with Azure IOT Hub

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub, firmware, mender

I have iot device developed by C programming, connecting to azure iot hub.
Can I use mender.io in my C application to update my firmware over the air

Answer (score 0):

Depends, I have not used it personally but did check it out as a possibility once. Check if you can integrate mender into your board https://hub.mender.io/c/board-integrations

If it is possible then I would suggest looking at some resources mender provides on how to do so.

Get some results and post problems after you try it out once.